# Убрать пустое пространство

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу (списываю) стиль на `ScrollBar`.

Проблема в непонятном пустом пространстве, которое равно стандартной ширене `ScrollBar`. Как его убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стили:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarTrackThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Height="Auto"
                            Fill="Transparent" />
                        <Border x:Name="CornerScrollBarRectangle"
                        CornerRadius="7"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                            <Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                            <Setter TargetName="CornerScrollBarRectangle" Property="Height" Value="6" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffff8000" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#786441A4" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="7"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="GridRoot" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                            IsDirectionReversed="true"
                            Focusable="false">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb"
                                       Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarTrackThumb}"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ScrollBarBlink}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ff6441A4"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ccff8000"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ScrollBarBlink}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffff8000"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#cc6441A4"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Сам `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="_scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы посмотрите стандартный стиль `ScrollBar`, то можете найти там такую строчку:

```
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
```

За этим динамическим ресурсом кроется получение ширины скроллбара из настроек ОС.

Вся проблема кроется в ней. Просто переопределите `MinWidth` в своем новом стиле.